# Image gallery fullscreen images... $.vegas( 'slideshow')

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fullscreen, image-gallery

We're are currently using a fullscreen image slideshow on a site, initial tests work a treat and the code below shows how this works:

```
$.vegas( 'slideshow' , {
    backgrounds:[
    { src:'/uploads/images/1397/lmwp_02.jpg', fade:1000 },
    { src:'/uploads/images/1397/lmwp_03.jpg', fade:1000 },
    { src:'/uploads/images/1397/lmwp_04.jpg', fade:1000 }
    ]
})('overlay');
```

What we would like to do is write the images in dynamically from our CSM. The was I'm currently doing this is to spit out a simple list like this:

```
<ul id="homeSlides">    
    <li><a href="/uploads/images/001.jpg">001</a></li>
    <li><a href="/uploads/images/002.jpg">002</a></li>
</ul>
```

What we need to do is get this list of images and inject it into the $.vegas backgrounds:[] function list...

I have tried the code below and can get the list of images, but I'm not sure how you would go about getting it into the $.vegas function:

```
var homeImgURLs = [];
    $('#homeSlides li a').each(function(index) {
    homeImgURLs.push('{ src:' + $(this).attr('href') + ', fade:1000}');
});
```

hence the post here. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
var homeImgURLs = [];
$('#homeSlides li a').each(function(index) {
  homeImgURLs.push({
    src: $(this).attr('href'),
    fade: 1000
  });
});

$.vegas( 'slideshow' , {
  backgrounds: homeImgURLs
})('overlay');
```

In your example you were pushing a string into the `homeImgURLs` array when you want to be pushing an object.