# Loading images dynamically into Vegas full screen background image plugin

Tags: jquery, image, wordpress, background

I'm trying to load images dynamically ::: Have the following code in WordPress :::

This is how I plan on getting the image data :::

```
//For Demo I'm simulating some data
$url = 'http://localhost/lolo-wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/image_02.jpg,http://localhost/mocha/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/image_02.jpg';


$urls = explode(',', $url);

    if( is_array($urls) ) {

      // $vega_bg ='';
      foreach( $urls as $url ) {
         $vega_bg[] = "{ src:'{$url}' }";
      }
    }
```

localizing all the attributes I'd like to send to Vegas :::

```
// Localization 
wp_localize_script( 'vegas_init', 'vegassettings', array(
  'delay' => 5000,
  'fade'  => 1000,
  'backgrounds' => $vega_bg
));
```

My Vegas initialization :::

```
vega_delay = parseInt(vegassettings.delay);
vega_fade = parseInt(vegassettings.fade);
vega_bg = vegassettings.backgrounds;


vega_att = {
    fade:vega_fade,
    delay:vega_delay,
    backgrounds:[ vega_bg ]
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

          jQuery.vegas('slideshow', 
            vega_att
          )
          ('overlay');

        function preloadImg(imgPath) {
          preloadImg = new Image();
          preloadImg.src = imgPath;
        } 

}); //Doc load
```

This is not working ::: However if I alert(vega_bg) I get the following **vega_bg = { src:'http://localhost/mocha/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/image_01.jpg' },{ src:'http://localhost/lolo-wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/image_02.jpg' },**

If I replace `vega_att` with the above copied string everything works ::: Any help will be appreciated :::

This is what the initialization outputs in my HTML :::

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var vegassettings = {"delay":"5000","fade":"1000","backgrounds":["{ src:'http:\/\/localhost\/lolo-wp\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/10\/slider-02.jpg' }","{ src:'http:\/\/localhost\/mocha\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/11\/hdr-076.jpg' }"]};
/* ]]> */
```

I suspect my issues has something to do with the back-slashes :::

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get my implementation to work ::: However I found another post with a reasonable workaround, I went ahead and implemented this posts option and it works really well  [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342823/image-gallery-fullscreen-images-vegas-slideshow)